# can google o3d and jQuery be used in the same page?

Tags: jquery, 3d, javascript, o3d

I would like to use both of these library on the same page but they seem to conflict when they are loaded at the same time. Does anyone know of any examples where they are both used or what might help prevent conflicts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this was due to the o3d code I had setting `window.onload = init()` function of my o3d code.

commenting out that line and adding:

```
jQuery(function() {

  init();

}
```

at the end solves the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You are probably looking for the jQuery noconflict mode:

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/

Comment: this doesn't seem to be doing the trick. I think there is something odd that happens when jQuery is loaded and how o3d initializes itself

Comment: Then, I'm afraid I don't have an answer, sorry.